# Gradient of Rayleigh's Quotient in complex case

Tags: complex-analysis

Giving the Rayleigh's Quotient in the real case ($x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$): $$R_A(x)=\frac{^t{x}Ax}{^t{x}x}$$ I know how to obtain the gradient, which is: $$\nabla R_A(x)=\frac{2}{^t{x}x}(Ax-R_A(x)x)$$
This involves calculating such things as: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial{x_i}}(x_1,...,x_i,...,x_n)$$
But now, in a complex case ($x\in\mathbb{C}^n$, $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$), we have: $$R_A(x)=\frac{^t{\overline{x}}Ax}{^t{\overline{x}}x}$$
So, this would involve calculating: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial{x_i}}(\overline{x_1},...,\overline{x_i},...,\overline{x_n})$$
and, as far as I remember, an expression such as $\frac{\partial{\overline{z}}}{\partial{z}}$ doesn't exist... Does it mean that the gradient of Rayleigh' Quotient doesn't exist in the complex case ? Or, am I missing something ?